# sis uninstaller don't remove entry from control panel

Tags: nsis, uninstallation

I have a NSIS script (generated from the wizard) that performs uninstall like this:

```
!define PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MyProgram.exe"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY "HKLM"
...
Section -Post
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" "" "$INSTDIR\MyProgram.exe"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"   "DisplayName" "$(^Name)"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "UninstallString" "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayIcon" "$INSTDIR\MyProgram.exe"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayVersion" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "URLInfoAbout" "${PRODUCT_WEB_SITE}"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "Publisher" "${PRODUCT_PUBLISHER}"
SectionEnd
```

... at the end of the script I have:

```
DeleteRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"
DeleteRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}"
SetAutoClose true
```

The problem is that after launching the uninstaller, the entry of MyProgram in Control Panel - Programs table remains.
What's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And the DeleteRegKey instructions are in a uninstaller section? Please post a full example script that reproduces the issue and please tell us the version of Windows you are using.

Comment: Yes, DeleteRegKey is in Section Uninstall, before the DeleteRegKey lines there are only files and directories deletions. I'm using Windows 8.1 but the issue is present also in Win7 and Win10

Comment: Things like RequestExectionLevel might affect things so it is very annoying when you don't post a complete script I can actually compile!

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine for me on Windows 8:

```
!define PRODUCT_NAME "MyTest"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION 1.0
!define PRODUCT_WEB_SITE http://example.com
!define PRODUCT_PUBLISHER ACME
Name "MyTest"
OutFile "Test.exe"
RequestExecutionLevel admin
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\$(^Name)"


Page Directory
Page InstFiles

!define PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MyProgram.exe"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY "HKLM"

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
; File "MyProgram.exe"
SectionEnd

Section -Post
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" "" "$INSTDIR\MyProgram.exe"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"   "DisplayName" "$(^Name)"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "UninstallString" "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayIcon" "$INSTDIR\MyProgram.exe"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayVersion" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "URLInfoAbout" "${PRODUCT_WEB_SITE}"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "Publisher" "${PRODUCT_PUBLISHER}"
SectionEnd

Section Uninstall
DeleteRegKey ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"
DeleteRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}"
#SetAutoClose true
SectionEnd
```

My only suggestion is to try [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and see if the uninstaller fails to delete the uninstall key...